# What is the estimated cost of validating a psychometric test?

Tags: measurement, validation

I had a conversation with my colleague about the estimated cost for validating a psychometric test (e.g., personality test in I/O psychology)

How many people should be included and what are they job description?

Comment: what's "io" and "ie"? I'd edit your english, but I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: i-o industrial organizational
ie - id est (latin)